# RESTful API in Node.js - Is Filtering Possible With Authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

I have a web application and a RESTful API to communicate with the DB. The frontend of the web application posts/gets/puts to the backend with Angular HTTP, which in turn handles authentication, posts/gets/puts to the api and returns the result. The backend authenticates itself as an admin to the API via JWT, but authenticates the users with cookie based sessions. So, in a way the API is stateless but the web server uses states.

I have been looking for options to have an authorization mechanism to filter query results based on users. For example I have a questions endpoint where I return a list of questions only created by the company of the logged in user.

1- I have been doing on the web server (basically filtering):

```
router.get('/questions', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    restler.get(process.env.API_URL + '/questions/?organisation=' + req.user.organisation._id).on('complete', function(questions) {
      res.json({
        data: questions
      });
    });
});
```

2- However the other option is the put questions endpoint nested under the user's organisation endpoint, such as:

```
/user/organisation/questions
```

3- Or basically I can put the user in the body of the request made to the API, which will filter based on the organisation of the user that is on the body of the request.

4- Finally, I can skip the cookie based session auth on the web server, make my request directly to the API from frontend and authenticate users using JWT (which is the same how to filter question in the first point).

I am fairly new to Node.js and I was wondering if there's a module or a common practice to handle particularly filtering in 1 or 4.

Comment: I assume that restler is a router? Or is the name of the nodejs app?

Comment: @sarker306 It is a HTTP client library. https://github.com/danwrong/restler That block is in the router itself, adding organisation info to the request made to the API.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that this is just a response from an user who has tried to follow the pattern practices.

I have been using Express framework. Using express, you can handle http requests fairly easily, and this is one of the most popular frameworks for web Development using Nodejs.

To solve the authorization problem, I would add a middleware (which can be a function) that would make filtering possible. For example, if  `router` is the name of the router which would handle all the requests and send replies, I would add the following code in `router.js`, the file where all router specific logic will be saved:

```
router.use(function isAuthorized(req, res, next){
    // Add your filtering code here
});
```

In this case, it would be,

```
router.use(passportConf.isAuthenticated);
```

Use this once, and every hit in your router will have to go through this middleware.

Now, we are trying to incorporate 'GET' request:

```
var http = require('http'); //basic node.js module, needed for handling http requests

router.get('/questions', function(req, res) {
    var url = process.env.API_URL;
    var opt = {host: url, path : '/questions/?organisation=' + req.user.organisation._id}
    http.request(opt, function(questions){
        res.json({data: questions});
    }).end();
});
```

Comment: This does not remotely answer my question, and API_URL starts with http://api.ABC.com Basically it is some other VM in my network I don't see how adding a slash would make my life easier.

Comment: Basically I am trying to demonstrate you don't need to use another module for handling http requests, if you're using Express. Reload to get the updated response.

Comment: I am not "handling" an HTTP request, I am "making" an HTTP request to my API server.

Comment: I am sorry this has nothing to do with my question of authorization. There is a reason why I am using restler, and in the example you posted, you are using 'http' module to make the request. I am grateful that you are trying to answer my question anyway, but my question is not how to make the request.

Comment: Well, in that case, I should ask if you are willing to make your web server stateless, just like the API? In that case, using JWT would help. In my understanding, option 4 would require you to send the access token in your request header "x-access-token", and decode it in server end to find the corresponding user if any. After that step, you could add decoded user to the request, and continue filtering. If that's what you would like, I can update my answer.

Comment: That is quite an improvement, and a valid option.